# Find and replace first comma in line with space

Tags: windows, regex, notepad++

Find and replace first comma in line with a space, for all lines in a file, and for all files in a directory.  Windows based solutions only please, I don't have sed etc. I have notepad++ o a regex would be good.

Comment: You should add tags for your restrictions.  And you should get a proper toolset so you’re not stuck with stuff like this.  These are easier to install and use than to live without them.

Comment: I don't know what kind of regex Notepad++ supports, but you can do this very easily. `^([^,]*),(.*)$` and replace with `\1 \2`.

Comment: If you don't have `sed, etc`, I suggest you _do_ get them. They'll make your life a hell of a lot easier. Without them, you may as well be running a marathon with your feet tied together.

Comment: Do you have a question? Stack Overflow is for asking questions, not giving instructions.

Comment: @Skurmedel: NPP's regex capabilities are appallingly limited, but I tested your solution and it worked.  You might as well post that as an answer.

Comment: @Alan Moore: LOL okay :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I might install Linux on a virtual machine, the tools are immensely better.  I am surprised ms hasn't written versions of the tools.

Comment: @Mark: If you have Windows Ultimate I think their are available... otherwise one has to resort to cygwin or gnuwin32.

Answer (score 3):

Get all non-comma characters before a comma into group 1. Match a comma. Get all the characters to line end/end of input into group 2.

```
^([^,]*),(.*)$
```

Replace with group 1 + " " + group 2.

```
\1 \2
```

---

Or...

1. Download sed.
2. Run it with `sed 's/,/ /' blah1 > blah2`
3. ???
4. Profit

Comment: @Mark You’ll find that `perl -pe 's/,/ /'` does the same thing — and much more.